# iterating thru fields in html form and passing them to function in python with flask

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

i have following html with n groups of input:

```
    <form action="{{ url_for('list_names') }}" method="POST">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input name="peson_name" type="text">
        <label>Age</label>
        <input name="person_age" type="number">

        <label>Name</label>
        <input name="peson_name" type="text">
        <label>Age</label>
        <input name="person_age" type="number">
    </form>
```

i would like to iterate thru every input and pass them to python function using flask and create list of dictionaries

```
@app.route('/list_names', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def list_names():
    if request.method == 'POST':
```

and this is where I stuck. the output that i'm looking for is a list of dictionaries that should ideally looks like this:

```
[
    {
    'name': 'person1',
    'age': 25
    },
    {
    'name': 'person2',
    'age': 30
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`request.form.getlist(...)`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist) all values from input fields with the specified name can be queried. The lists of names and ages obtained in this way can be combined using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). Thus, pairs are formed from the values that have the same index. Then it is only necessary to form a dictionary from the received tuples.

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    render_template,
    request
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/list_names', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def list_names():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        names = request.form.getlist('person_name')
        ages = request.form.getlist('person_age', type=int)
        data = [{ 'name': name, 'age': age } for name,age in zip(names, ages)]
        print(data)
    return render_template('list_names.html')
```